# How to replace a string by 2 strings simultaneously

Tags: python, string, function, replace

I need to replace a string `("AB")` with another 2 strings simultaneously (A -> -BF+AFA+FB- and B -> +AF-BFB-FA+ ) via a function that has one input `(sequence)`.

So far I have:

```
def replace_function(sequence):
    for i in sequence:
        string = sequence.replace("A","-BF+AFA+FB-").replace("B","+AF-BFB-FA+")
    return string

replace_function("AB")

>>> -+AF-BFB-FA+F+AFA+F+AF-BFB-FA+-+AF-BFB-FA+
```

However, I need:

```
replace_function("AB")
>>> -BF+AFA+FB-+AF-BFB-FA+
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def replace_function(s):
    # define a dictionary to keep track of what character to change into
    d_map = {'A': '-BF+AFA+FB-',
             'B': '+AF-BFB-FA+'}
    lst = []
    # iterate all characters of the string
    for c in s:
        # if character is in the dictionary
        if c in d_map:
            # append value 
            lst.append(d_map[c])
        else:
            # if character not in the dictionary, add it back to the list
            lst.append(c)
    # join the list and return
    return ''.join(lst)


ret = replace_function('AB')
print(ret)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to simply build a new string based on the old one.  Build a translation dict to help you.

For each character, if it's in your translation table, take the translation.  If not, just keep the original character.  Join them all into your new string.

```
xlate = {
    "A": "-BF+AFA+FB-",
    "B": "+AF-BFB-FA+"
}

new_str = ''.join([xlate[char] if char in xlate 
                               else char
             for char in sequence])
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over your `sequence` and replace characters one by one:

```
def replace_function(sequence):
    replacement = {'A': '-BF+AFA+FB-',
                   'B': '+AF-BFB-FA+'}
    return ''.join(replacement.get(c, c) for c in sequence)
```

Note that `replacement.get(c, c)` will returned mapped value if `c` exists in the `replacement` dictionary and return `c` otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You could match capture either A or match B and do the replacement checking for the group 1 value.

```
import re

def replace_function(sequence):
    return re.sub(
        r"(A)|B",
        lambda m: "-BF+AFA+FB-" if m.group(1) else "+AF-BFB-FA+",
        sequence
    )
```

Output

```
-BF+AFA+FB-+AF-BFB-FA+
```

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/djUQbv)

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what your use case is, but i would define an empty string and then append.

Thus

```
newstring = ""
for i in sequence:
    if i == "A":
        newstring.append("-BF+AFA+FB-")
    if i == "B":
        newstring.append("+AF-BFB-FA+")
return newstring
```

Answer (score 0):

Every answer so far has interpreted the question as - replace A with an X that contains As and Bs, and B with a Y that may also contain As and Bs (which I think is the intended question).

OP asked for a specific case where A and B are placed together and might be intending to pass in a larger sequence where AB should be replaced by a single entity, but 'ABB' should come out as >> `-BF+AFA+FB-+AF-BFB-FA+B` , not -`BF+AFA+FB-+AF-BFB-FA++AF-BFB-FA+`

Assuming this to be the case, here is my slightly different answer from the other solutions that takes into account that 'AB' should be processed together

```
def replace_function(sequence):
    new_string = ''
    for idx, s in enumerate(sequence):
        if idx < len(sequence) - 1:
            if sequence[idx] == 'A' and sequence[idx + 1] == 'B':
                new_string += "-BF+AFA+FB-+AF-BFB-FA+"
            elif sequence[idx - 1] == 'A' and sequence[idx] == 'B':
                continue
            else:
                new_string += s
        elif sequence[idx - 1] != 'A':
            new_string += s
    print(new_string)


replace_function("AB")  # -BF+AFA+FB-+AF-BFB-FA+
replace_function("ABC")  # -BF+AFA+FB-+AF-BFB-FA+C
replace_function("ABCBA")  # -BF+AFA+FB-+AF-BFB-FA+CBA
replace_function("ABCBAB")  # -BF+AFA+FB-+AF-BFB-FA+CB-BF+AFA+FB-+AF-BFB-FA+
```